# Regarding Android Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hot To Create A Table in database only once and insert data into that table multiple times in android using SQLite DB...??

Comment: You will get 100 examples for this one if you search on google. Please do some research first before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sub-classing [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and making use of its convenience methods which will remove a lot of the complexity of using SQLite. See [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Take a look at the [NotePadProvider](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is my activity class

```
public class d extends Activity {
   
 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
  
 
 
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        
        String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String email=getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        String phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
      
        Log.e("d3","came to other activity");
        SmartDBHelper d=new SmartDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
       d.open();
       d.insertTitle(name, phone, email);
      Cursor c=d.getAllTitles();
      // c.getColumnName(0); 
      
      for( int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
      if(c.moveToNext()){
          Log.e("c", ""+ c.getString(0) );    
          Log.e("d", ""+ c.getString(1) );
          Log.e("d4", ""+ c.getString(2) );   
          
          
      }
    Log.e("r",""+c.getCount());
    finish();
      }
    
    }
}
```

here is my sqllite class

```
public class SmartDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  
    
    private SQLiteDatabase dBH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yo.db";  
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;  
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME = "user_notify_data"; 
    private static final String HR_TABLE_NAME = "user_hr_data";  
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE =  
        "CREATE TABLE " + NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME + " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
        "userresponse TEXT, " + 
        "notifytime TEXT);";  
    
    
    private static final String HR_TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + HR_TABLE_NAME +  
        " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +   
        "hr TEXT, " + 
        "act TEXT, " + 
        "timestamp TEXT);";
    
    public SmartDBHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub   
        }  
        
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
            Log.e("smartdbhelper", "before creation");    
            db.execSQL(NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE);      
            Log.e("smartdbhelper", "middle creation"); 
            db.execSQL(HR_TABLE_CREATE);       
            Log.e("smartdbhelper", "after creation");  
            }   
        
        @Override   
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
            } 
    
        public SmartDBHelper open() throws SQLException 
        {
              dBH = getWritableDatabase(); 
             return this;
        }

        public long insertTitle(String isbn, String title, String publisher) 
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put("hr", isbn);
            initialValues.put("act", title);
            initialValues.put("timestamp", publisher);
            Log.e("insertes","i");
           
             dBH.insert(HR_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
return 11111111; 
        }


        
        public Cursor getAllTitles() 
        {
            return dBH.query(HR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                     "hr","act","timestamp"},null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
        }



        
        
        
        
        
        //---closes the database---    
        public void close() 
        {
            close();
        

}  
    
}
```

The above code works and has been tested